# Get array values by return from a Javascript function containing ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to read `product_info` array returned from function `getproductInfo` containing a ajax call but I still getting `undefined` value on console.log. Also, I'm using a callback function but still doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function successCallback(data)
    {
        var name = data.name;
        var image = data.image;
        var link = data.link;

        var product_info = [name, image, link];
        console.log(product_info); // Correct: show my product_info array
        return product_info;
    }

    function getProductInfo(prodId, successCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getProductInfo.php",
            data: "id=" + prodId,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var p_info = successCallback(data);
                console.log(p_info); // Correct: show my product_info array
                return p_info;    
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Error getProductInfo()...");
            }
        });

        return p_info; // Wrong: show "undefined" value
    }

    var p_info = getProductInfo(12, successCallback);
    console.log(p_info); // Wrong: show empty value
});
```

Comment: The order of the two logs should get you started: the response arrives (and the success callback is called) only some time after you logged `undefined`.

Comment: it is due to ajax call.

Comment: Thank you, but how can resolve?